# Looking for an elegant Rx.NET way to implement certain data processing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

Given:

1. Database as the source of the data
2. The data has to be grouped and aggregated, where the aggregation process must be done in code and is asynchronous.

I am using the following simple code to simulate the real life:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ObservableTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public int Key;
            private int m_previous = -1;

            public async Task<Result> AggregateAsync(int x)
            {
                return await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                    Debug.Assert(m_previous < 0 ? x == Key : m_previous == x - 10);
                    m_previous = x;
                    return this;
                });
            }

            public int Complete()
            {
                Debug.Assert(m_previous / 10 == 9);
                return Key;
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var obs = GetSource()
                .GroupBy(x => x % 10)
                .SelectMany(g => g.Aggregate(Observable.Return(new Result { Key = g.Key }), (resultObs, x) => resultObs.SelectMany(result => result.AggregateAsync(x).ToObservable()))
                .Merge()
                .Select(x => x.Complete()));

            obs.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit ..."));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static IObservable<int> GetSource()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).SelectMany(remainder => Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => 10 * i + remainder)).ToObservable();
        }
    }
}
```

The `GetSource` returns numbers from 0 to 99 in a certain order. The order already matches the one needed for the grouping. View this method as if it was quering a database using a SQL statement with `ORDER BY` matching the anticipated grouping.

So, having an observable of database content I need to group it, aggregate asynchronously and replace each group with the aggregation result.

Here is my solution (from the code above):

```
var obs = GetSource()
    .GroupBy(x => x % 10)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Aggregate(Observable.Return(new Result { Key = g.Key }), (resultObs, x) => resultObs.SelectMany(result => result.AggregateAsync(x).ToObservable()))
    .Merge()
    .Select(x => x.Complete()));
```

I see multiple problems with it:

1. `GroupBy` is wrong here, because the data is already in the right order. It should be a sort of `Window` or `Buffer`, but driven by a predicate rather than sample count or time interval.
2. The asynchronous aggregation looks cumbersome and hence I assume I botched it too.

What is the proper Rx.NET way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure whether there is a proper Rx way to solve this problem but things start getting messy in Rx when dealing with collections especially when items need to be added, updated or removed.

I wrote [DynamicData](http://dynamic-data.org/) an open source project which specifically deals with manipulating collections. So my disclaimer with this answer is I am very biased as to the solution.

Back to the problem, I would instantiate an observable cache like this

```
var myCache = new SourceCache<MyObject, MyId>(myobject=>myobject.Id)
```

You can now observe the cache and apply operators. To group and apply some transforms do the following

```
var mystream = myCache.Connect()
   .Group(myobject => // group value) //creates an observable a cache for each group
   .Transform((myGroup,key) => myGroup.Cache.Connect().QueryWhenChanged(query=> //aggregate result)
//now do something with the result
```

where Transform is an overload of Rx Select operator. I previous blogged a detailed solution which may be appropriate to your problem here [Aggregation Example](http://dynamic-data.org/2015/02/23/trading-demo-part-5-aggregate-dynamic-data/).

This cache is thread safe and you can use the addorupdate and remove methods to load and change it asynchronously.

Comment: Why is it relevant? I do not add/remove/update existing items. I transform one sequence of items into another. My understanding is that I am completely within the realm of functional programming and hence Reactive should shine here.

Answer (score 0):

Remember by default RX avoids concurrency. However, if you need to you can introduce schedulers to assign work when you want it.

Per your comments:

1. I don't believe using GroupBy Is bad here at all if you want a predicate to drive the partitioning.
2. my approach is below (can paste into linqpad with the reactive library included). I still struggling with warping my mind with observable but I believe this follows a good idiom as it's also shown by microsoft at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242963%28v=vs.103%29.aspx (last example)

   ```
   void Main()

   {
   Console.WriteLine("starting on thread {0}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

   //GetSource()
   //.GroupBy(x => x % 10)
   var sharedSource = GetSource().Publish();

   var closingSignal = sharedSource.Where(MyPredicateFunc);

   sharedSource.Window(()=>closingSignal)
   .Select(x => x.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default))
   .SelectMany(g=>g.Aggregate(0, (s,i) =>ExpensiveAggregateFunctionNoTask(s,i)).SingleAsync())
   .Subscribe(i=>Console.WriteLine("Got {0} on thread {1}",i,Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
   ;

   sharedSource.Connect();

   }// Define other methods and classes here

   bool MyPredicateFunc(int i){
        return (i %10 == 0);
   }

   static IObservable<int> GetSource()
   {
      return Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
       .SelectMany(remainder => Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => 10 * i + remainder)).ToObservable();
   }


   int ExpensiveAggregateFunctionNoTask(int lastResult, int currentElement){
   var r = lastResult+currentElement;
   Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} and {1} on thread {2}", lastResult, currentElement, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
   Task.Delay(250).Wait(); //simulate expensive operation
   return r;
   }
   ```

Doing this you will see that the we have created a new thread for each grouping made and then we wait async in the SelectMany.

Comment: GroupBy has to accumulate the entire sequence. But this is a waste if the sequence is already ordered correctly and the groups follow one after another without interleaving. This should allow for a more efficient implementation than with GroupBy.

Comment: GroupBy produces an observable of Observables. It starts producing on the very first element. So in the example above each Aggregate runs on its' own partition and therefore on it's own thread.
If you know ahead of time that things are ordered already, why not just start an observable yourself for each partition then yes groupby is not required.

Comment: That's exactly part of my question. If the data is ordered, I need to use sort of a Window operator with a predicate. But I could not find one.

Comment: So what you want is a function that still returns an IObservable<IObservable<T>> like groupBy does? I added a different implementation that uses the window extension method